# How to permanently diable block caret in pycharm

Tags: pycharm

In Pycharm community version since 2 days block caret i.e. the thick cursor line is disturbing a lot. when I copy the code it will be automatically changes to block caret. This is bringing a lot of headache while typing long code or while selecting the code. Please any one help me out from this. I Have even tried unselecting **Use Block Caret** in settings and also tried **insert** button as short cut but It didn't work. Please help me.

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks you have accidentally installed IdeaVim plugin so you basically have a vim emulation running in the editor. Disable it with **Tools | Vim Emulator** or remove the plugin completely from **Settings | Plugins**.